# Windowsフォームアプリにおけるスワイプによるスクロールについて

Tags: c#, windows, wpf, winforms

現在C#/.net4.5環境においてWindowsフォームを使った
Win8タブレット向けのアプリケーションを作成しています。

アプリでは、

> ■PanelA
>   ├■Button1
>   ├■Button2
>   ├■Button3
>   …

といった形で、パネルの子コントロールとしてボタンを並べて配置している箇所があります。
このとき、PanelAにはスクロールバーが表示される状態になっており、
PanelA上の何も無い箇所をスワイプするとスクロールを行ってくれるのですが、
Button上を起点にスワイプするとスクロールされません。

調べて試してみたのですが、WPFではScrollViewer.PanningModeを設定することで、
ボタン上からのスワイプによってスクロールされることを確認しました。
ただ、WPFとの混合運用は極力避けたいと考えており、
まずはWindowsフォームでそもそもこの機構を実現するのは難しいのかどうかも合わせて、
ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: WPFが使用可能であれば、WPFに統一したほうが良いかと思います。フォームにWPFのようなルーティングイベントの概念は、無いため、Buttonクラスを継承し、親コントロールに伝播する形になります。必要であれば、Win32APIレベルで行う必要があるかも知れません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
そもそも全く異なる概念であるという認識が足りていなかったようです。
WPFへの移行を検討させていただきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button`の様なクリックのみで動作するコントロールであれば、`MouseDown`や`MouseMove`の中で親コントロールに`Capture`を設定すれば親がドラッグされているかのように動作させられます。下のコードはクリックをキャンセルしてPanelを水平スクロールさせるサンプルになります。

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _PreviousX;

    public Form1()
    {
        // デザイナー上ではpanel1の中にButtonが水平に並べてあります。
        InitializeComponent();

        // パネル内のコントロールにイベントハンドラーを設定
        foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
        {
            c.Click += (s, args) => MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
            c.MouseDown += Button_MouseDown;
            c.MouseMove += Button_MouseMove;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // パネルが普通にクリックされた場合
        panel1.Capture = true;
        _PreviousX = panel1.PointToScreen(e.Location).X;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Capture)
        {
            // パネルのドラッグ処理
            var x = panel1.PointToScreen(e.Location).X;
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = Math.Min(
                                                Math.Max(
                                                    panel1.HorizontalScroll.Minimum,
                                                    panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value + _PreviousX - x),
                                                    panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum);
            _PreviousX = x;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Capture = false;
    }

    private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // ボタンがクリックされた場合
        var c = (Control)sender;

        c.Capture = true;

        _PreviousX = c.PointToScreen(e.Location).X;
    }

    private void Button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = (Control)sender;
        if (c.Capture)
        {
            // ボタンが押された状態である程度動いたらpanel1にイベントを付け替える
            var x = panel1.PointToScreen(e.Location).X;
            if (Math.Abs(x - _PreviousX) > 3)
            {
                c.Capture = false;
                panel1.Capture = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
いただいたサンプルコードで一度動作を確認させていただきましたところ、
子コントロール上を起点としてスワイプに反応することを確認いたしました。
恥ずかしながら、Captureプロパティの存在自体を知りませんでした。

重ねての質問で恐縮ですが、
>PanelA上の何も無い箇所をスワイプするとスクロールを行ってくれるのですが、
このときのスワイプには慣性がついておりまして、
お教えいただいた手法と操作感が異なるためこれを統一したく、
このスワイプ処理をそのまま引き込める方法が無いかと考えております。

・そもそもWindowsフォームのスワイプはどのような仕組みで実現しているのか
・スワイプによる慣性をどういったタイミングで処理しているのか

こちらについてもご存知のことがあれば、お教えいただけると幸いです。

Comment: @nemak1d 標準のWindows Formコントロールではタッチ操作であっても慣性スクロールしないという認識ですが、何か追加のコンポーネントを使用されていますか？方針としては`Timer`等で独自にアニメーションを計算するか、既存のコンポーネントを騙して途中から慣性スクロールを行わせるかのどちらかだと思います。

Comment: ＠pgrho 特に使っていないです。が、タブレット側の機能で勝手にエミュレーションしているのかもしれません。いずれにしても慣性化する場合は独自に実装が必要だという旨に関しては理解しました。